# Add Rows or Columns to Matrix by Recycling

Tags: julia

I have a 2x2 matrix

```
a = [1 2
    3 4]

2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
```

and want to add a row of all `0`s. I can just do this:

```
vcat(0, a)

3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  0
 1  2
 3  4
```

The `0` gets recycled and fills up the entire first row. To me (coming from R) this makes sense.

What does not make sense to me is the following:

```
hcat(0, a)

ERROR: DimensionMismatch("mismatch in dimension 1 (expected 1 got 2)")
```

Anyone got an explanation?

Comment: I would say it is a bug as also `vcat(a, 0)` fails. I can see the reason why this works in the source code, but I think `vcat(0, a)` should be disallowed.

Comment: Julia does not support recycling; this is a bug.  https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/38019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reiterate what Matt and Bogumil said, Julia does not support recycling, it's a bug: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/38019